# MS SQL Server 2008 drops connections if number of connections is large

Tags: sql-server, database-connection, connection-refused

My SQL Server instance is configured for unlimited number of connecting users (DB right click - properties - connections). But when my script tries to execute about 500 simultaneous queries a big part of the connections fail with error "Connection refused" from the server:

```
2017/03/10 15:11:47 ERROR: Unable to open tcp connection with host 'db.mydomain.ru:1433': dial tcp 10.100.20.3:1433: getsockopt: connection refused
```

In Events and SQL Server logs I didn't find anything useful. What can be a problem?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This could be a possible configuration issue.  First, ensure that TCP/IP is enabled in SSCM by launching the Sql Server Configuration Manager > Sql Server Network Configuration> Protocols for the instance, in the right panel, TCP/IP should be "Enabled". If not, change this to Enabled, then, re-test.  If the issue is still occurring, you could try assigning the Sql Server instance a defined port number other than the default (1433). To do this: Launch SSCM, click on the protocols for the instance under the Sql Server Network Configuration (left panel), highlight the instance, open the properties of TCP/IP, on the protocol tab, ensure that Enabled is set to Yes, and on the IP address tab, ensure that the defined port numbers (other than 1433) is placed under the TCP Port entry for each IP listing.  At the bottom, under IPALL, remove the dynamic port entry and place that defined port number in the entry as well.  Restart Sql Server (instance) for this to take effect.  Then, test again to see if the problem still exists.

Comment: May be I said incorrectly in description but the point is that my SQL Server accepts and handles connections in usual way. It starts dropping only when number of simultaneous connections is large (over 500, experimentally)